# How to clone and re-face Ruby on Rails app with seprate database.

Tags: ruby, github, clone, jetbrains-ide, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Building a ROR app (rails 5), pushing to github, using jet brains - ruby mine IDE and after building 1st app would like to use all the same code, class names and gems ect. with the exception of changing css and front page design. of the second app. Second app will operated totaly seprate and seprate DB simply a new and differnt home page desihn. I am still new at ruby and just like most dont fully understand the "magic". What do I have to keep in mind? especially with gems dont fully understand what is loaded in all the files. does all the gems come over to new app with all the elements installed? Are there addtional steps with the new app to install. Is this a very difficult? just what you may have experianced as I know it depends on ones skillset. Thanks for all your feed back I look forward to it.

Comment: (1)Clone the repo into a new local repo. (2)Change the remote repo. (3)Change the config/database.yml file. (4)Redesign your UI. (5)Push to new remote repo. Done

Comment: Fantastic! That’s a load off my mind. Thanks for your direction